# How can I get ChemSketch to get N and H atoms closer while still operating in ACS style and without adjusting atom sizes?

Tags: software

A person at wikipedia is getting on my case for creating this image because the N and H symbols are so separated even though this seems to be the default of [ChemSketch](http://www.acdlabs.com/resources/freeware/chemsketch/) (one of the softwares that's recommended for chem structure drawing in the Wikipedia manual of style) and I'd like to know how to make them happy and get the separation between the N and H shortened without changing the style and letter sizes.

[image]

Comment: You could explicitly draw in the N-H bond.